# How can I prevent overwriting my javascript array and send it to a hidden field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hidden-field

My function below measures reaction time for a keypress event. It prints it on the screen in the 'time' div but only gives the last reaction time, and it should push each reaction time into an array (react_time_arr).
What I would like to achieve is (lower part of my code):

a) that each reaction time (for 10 runs) is printed to the hidden field 'outp' which in the end stores 10 consecutive reaction times, and

b) that I can check the content of the hidden field in the 'time' div, and

c) that after 10 runs I see reaction time 8, 9, 10 in the 'proxy_print' div.

Can you help me?

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="outp" name="output" value="" />

    <div id="time">RT: </div>
    <div id="proxy_print"></div>
```

JS

```
var reac_time_arr = []; var t1; var i = 0;
var ISI = [100, 200, 300];
var SPT = 1000;
$(function(){
    var timeout = 0;
    function showNext() {
        if(isNaN($("#time").text()) ){
            $("#time").text("1000");
            }
        t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
            if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
            var new_word = stim[Math.floor((Math.random()*stim.length)+1)].name;
            $("#abc").text(new_word);
            } else {
            var new_img =  stim[Math.floor((Math.random()*stim.length)+1)].path;
            $("#abc").empty();
            var prox_img = $('<img id="abcimg" height="300px" width="300px">');
            prox_img.attr('src', new_img);
            prox_img.appendTo('#abc');
            }
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){showNext()}, SPT);
    }
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
            if ($(e.target).is('input, textarea') || i > 10) {
                return;
            };
        i++;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            if (e.which === 97 || e.which === 108 || e.which === 32) {
              setTimeout(function(){showNext();}, ISI[Math.floor(Math.random() * ISI.length)]);
            var t2 = (new Date()).getTime();
              var reac_time = t2-t1;
            reac_time_arr.push(reac_time);
            $("#time").text(reac_time);
            $("#outp").val(reac_time_arr);
            $("#proxy_print").text((reac_time_arr[reac_time_arr.length-3]));
                }
    });
});
```

Comment: You should remove the `+1` from the random selection

Comment: What is the ISI? Where is it defined? What does it contain?